# eval() to execute code from a textbox 

Tags: php, curl, eval

I'm trying to make something like this http://writecodeonline.com/php/ for my own server. I can't use that service because I need to use cURL which they don't have enabled for obvious reasons.

This is the code I have so far.

For the first page where you enter the code you want to test.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<textarea name="code" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And to execute the code.

```
<?php
$result = eval($_POST['code']); 
echo $result;
?>
```

You can see the error codes if you try to use it here http://alexseyer.com/phptest.php

I know this is a security no-no but I have nothing of value on the server anyway.

Comment: They're just warnings, just put a `error_reporting(0);` at the top of your process.php and it'll be fine. (But beware, please block certain commands (passthru, system, and so on). I got your uptime. :) And oh yes, stripslashes. :)

Comment: @NoLifeKing hiding warning is not a solution.....

Comment: It would help people rather than make them go do something on your site, to say "I put in .." and got back "...."

Comment: @MiqdadAli That is true. But it would rid him of the ASCII-warnings (and all other error-messages too though). And no, I haven't only pasted a few lines of PHP in my days. :)

Comment: @Alex Seyer I think you are pasted only few lines code of pHP.

Comment: @Alex Seyer , pls remove the code "http://alexseyer.com/phptest.php" from ur server otherwise it will be a possibility to get hacked as ur using eval anyone can run code here..

Answer (score 2):

You could try the code below. Use `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` to check whether magic_quotes_gpc is on.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        echo eval_php(stripslashes($_POST['content']));
    else{
        echo eval_php($_POST['content']);
    }
}

function eval_php($content)
{
    ob_start();
    eval("?>$content<?php ");
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo 123;` works

the Problem is that quotation marks will be escaped with a backslash.
Have a look at [php:addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php), you can turn it off by [disabling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) the `magic_quotes` option.